Deamon depends on smb share(in fstab), problem at shutdown
I got a daemon which depends on a SMB share, which is mounted via fstab.
All is good at startup, but during a shutdown, the system attempts to unmount the share while the daemon is still running (daemon is S98 and K5 in rcx.d).  How can I make sure the daemon shuts down first?
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
